# Add Navigation Tabs to Tailwind CSS Navbar

Tags: css, tailwind-css

So I've designed this tailwind CSS navbar, but I'm having trouble adding tabs to it. Here is a link to my navbar. Hopefully, someone can help add some Dropdown menu, so I can use it in my project. I have tried every possible way, but it seems hard. I've even tried to use other components.
No matter what, I cannot get this navbar to work properly. I need to change the navbar away from static to responsive mode but it is currently not working. Any advice would be appreciated!!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
            return {
                open: false,
            }
      },
      methods: {
        toggle() {
            this.open = !this.open
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<header class="font-sans antialiased" id="app">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-grey-dark p-6">
      <div class="flex">
        <img src="src/assets/boy.svg" alt="" class="h-8 w-8">
        <a href="#" class="no-underline text-white text-bold mt-2"><span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">ExampleCss</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="block sm:hidden">
        <button @click="toggle" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-grey-dark-lighter border-grey-dark-light hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'" class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="text-sm sm:hidden">
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Home
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Expertise
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Academia
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Portfolio
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Blog
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Contact
          </a>
          <div class="flex">
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0 mr-2">Register</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0">Login</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden w-full block md:flex md:w-auto">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0 mr-2">Register</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="bg-grey-dark sm:block p-6" :class="open ? 'hidden': 'hidden'">
      <div class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center text-sm sm:flex-grow uppercase">
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Home
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Expertise
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Academia
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Portfolio
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Blog
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Contact
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/issues/301

Comment: I tried, but it's still not working on hover.

Comment: can you add jquery to your project in addition to vue.js???
https://bytutorial.com/blogs/vuejs/how-to-use-jquery-in-vuejs-2

Answer (score 1):

I have review your code and find one suggestion for drop-down menu, kindly replace my suggested code in your page and hopefully drop down working for your menu also.

HTML

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<header class="font-sans antialiased" id="app">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-grey-dark p-6">
      <div class="flex">
        <img src="src/assets/boy.svg" alt="" class="h-8 w-8">
        <a href="#" class="no-underline text-white text-bold mt-2"><span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">ExampleCss</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="block sm:hidden">
        <button @click="toggle" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-grey-dark-lighter border-grey-dark-light hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title><path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div :class="open ? 'block': 'hidden'" class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="text-sm sm:hidden">
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Home
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Expertise
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Academia
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Portfolio
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Blog
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Contact
          </a>
          <div class="flex">
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0 mr-2">Register</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0">Login</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hidden w-full block md:flex md:w-auto">
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0 mr-2">Register</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline inline-block text-sm px-4 py-2 leading-none border rounded text-white border-white hover:border-transparent hover:text-gray hover:bg-white mt-4 sm:mt-0">Login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="bg-grey-dark sm:block p-6" :class="open ? 'hidden': 'hidden'">
      <div class="w-full flex-grow sm:flex sm:items-center sm:w-auto">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center text-sm sm:flex-grow uppercase">
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Home
          </a>
          <div id="app" class="p-6 font-sans leading-normal">
  <dropdown-link>
    <span slot="link" class="appearance-none flex items-center inline-block text-white font-medium px-4 py-2 rounded">
      <span class="mr-1">Dropdown</span>
      <svg class="h-4 w-4 fill-current" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
        <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />
      </svg>
    </span>
    <div slot="dropdown" class="bg-white shadow rounded border overflow-hidden">
      <a href="#" class="no-underline block px-4 py-3 border-b text-grey-darkest bg-white hover:text-white hover:bg-blue whitespace-no-wrap">Action</a>
      <a href="#" class="no-underline block px-4 py-3 border-b text-grey-darkest bg-white hover:text-white hover:bg-blue whitespace-no-wrap">Another action</a>
      <a href="#" class="no-underline block px-4 py-3 border-b text-grey-darkest bg-white hover:text-white hover:bg-blue whitespace-no-wrap">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </dropdown-link>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="dropdown-link-template">
  <div class="relative">
    <div role="button" class="inline-block select-none" @click="open = !open">
      <slot name="link"></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="absolute pin-l mt-px" v-show="open">
      <slot name="dropdown"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Expertise
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Academia
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Portfolio
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Blog
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="no-underline block mt-4 sm:inline-block sm:mt-0 text-white hover:text-white mr-8">
            Contact
          </a>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

vue.js

```
 Vue.component('dropdown-link', {
  template: '#dropdown-link-template',
  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

[image]

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakpanwar/mu51pqf9/)

Answer (score 0):

i researched some about this, i am assuming that you want to add dropdown without adding additional scripts or plugins, right. try the solution from following link

https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/dropdown-menu-without-js

Let me know if this works for you.